# Issues with Character Counter - Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have some code that is designed to count the amount of characters in the text of a website. Currently, it still counts `<style>` and `<script>` tags, even though I set it not to. Is there any way to fix this? My code is below.

new.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var length = $("body").contents().filter(function(){
    return (this.localName != "script" && this.localName != "style") ? true : false;
  }).text().replace(/ +/g, "").length;
```

Comment: @wOxxOm, so to do that it would look something like ```var length = $("body"):not(script, style)```?

Comment: @wOxxOm got it, will this work with <a> tags as well? So, ```$("body:not(script, style, a)")```?

Comment: Oops, should be this `$("body *:not(script, style, a)")`